# Database migration fail while using entity framework core

Tags: database, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework core and Package Manager Console in Visual Studio 2017 Community to do migrations by `add-migration` and `update-database` commands to apply changes from my model to database.
I'm trying to do migration with `update-database` command and it fails all the time with the error :
"ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because 'UserIDUser' is the only data column in table 'UserGroups'. A table must have at least one data column."
I don't know what to do with this, now I can't apply any changes that I made in my model code in application. I've already made some updates to database with the same manner couple times and everything was fine until now. What I've done in the model is deleting one field from `UserGroup` entity (`IDUserGroup` specifically) but I don't know is that reason of my troubles.

How can I repair this ?

This is the code (migration designer file) from my previous migration that was updated to database successfully and another that I can't update to database :

**Previous `update-database` (successful) :**

```
[DbContext(typeof(DBContext))]
[Migration("20170726113245_Privatemigration")]
partial class Privatemigration
{
    protected override void BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "1.1.2")
            .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

       modelBuilder.Entity("Server.Models.Group", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("IDGroup")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                b.Property<string>("Description");

                b.Property<string>("GroupName")
                    .IsRequired();

                b.HasKey("IDGroup");

                b.ToTable("Groups");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Server.Models.User", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("IDUser")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                b.Property<string>("Forename")
                    .IsRequired();

                b.HasKey("IDUser");

                b.ToTable("Users");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Server.Models.UserGroup", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("IDUserGroup")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                b.Property<int?>("GroupIDGroup");

                b.Property<int?>("UserIDUser");

                b.HasKey("IDUserGroup");

                b.HasIndex("GroupIDGroup");

                b.HasIndex("UserIDUser");

                b.ToTable("UserGroups");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Server.Models.UserGroup", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("Server.Models.Group", "Group")
                    .WithMany("Groups")
                    .HasForeignKey("GroupIDGroup");

                b.HasOne("Server.Models.User", "User")
                    .WithMany("UserGroups")
                    .HasForeignKey("UserIDUser");
            });
    }
}
```

**Subsequent `update-database` (failed) :**

```
[DbContext(typeof(DBContext))]
[Migration("20170807142122_PrivateMigration2")]
partial class PrivateMigration2
{
    protected override void BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "1.1.2")
            .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

        modelBuilder.Entity("Server.Models.Group", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("IDGroup")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                b.Property<string>("Description");

                b.Property<string>("GroupName")
                    .IsRequired();

                b.HasKey("IDGroup");

                b.ToTable("Group");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Server.Models.User", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("IDUser")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                b.Property<string>("Forename")
                    .IsRequired();

                b.HasKey("IDUser");

                b.ToTable("Users");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Server.Models.UserGroup", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("IDUser");

                b.Property<int>("IDGroup");

                b.HasKey("IDUser", "IDGroup");

                b.HasIndex("IDGroup");

                b.ToTable("UserGroup");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Server.Models.UserGroup", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("Server.Models.Group", "Group")
                    .WithMany("UsersGroups")
                    .HasForeignKey("IDGroup")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

                b.HasOne("Server.Models.User", "User")
                    .WithMany("UsersGroups")
                    .HasForeignKey("IDUser")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried reproducing this. Basically join table with explicit PK and later converted to composite PK. While I got same migrations as you, I am still able to run update-database correctly. Based on the error & SQL being sent for the migration, I think your database is corrupted and it does not resemble how your last model was.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed to do update-database by making update-database of my first init migration and remove all migrations except this first. Then finally update-database worked and my recent changes in model are in database.